# Concatenate every n-th row

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I got a data set in a matrix like the following (imported from Excel):

```
matrix =
    Cat1   1  2  3  4
    Cat2   9 10 11 12
    Cat3  17 18 19 20
    Cat1   5  6  7  8
    Cat2  13 14 15 16
    Cat3  21 22 23 24
```

I would like to reshape it into 3 vectors (one for every category) of the same size to do a stacked bar plot. Vectors should look like this after reshape operation (It would be nice if the vector had the name of the first column and the matrix could be of any size):

```
cat1 = [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
cat2 = [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
cat3 = [17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
```

I sincerely hope this is not duplicate. I couldn't produce a working solution with the help of the other reshape questions.

Comment: Is `Cat1; Cat2...` etc a column of your matrix or do the categories definitely repeat every `n` rows?

Comment: what is the type of `matrix`? cell array, dataset object, ..?

Comment: @Dan Your assumption is correct.
@ Amro I imported the data as cell array, since the matrix option will replace my text values with NaN. I honestly dont know what the dataset type does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is a matrix, you can manipulate the order of the rows when indexing, so you can do something like this:

```
rows = reshape(1:size(matrix, 1), n, []).';
res = reshape(matrix(rows, :).', [], n).';
```

The resulting matrix `res` is composed of the concatenated rows.

This solution holds for cell arrays as well, but you'll need an additional `cell2mat` to turn the result into a matrix.

#### Example

```
matrix = [1:4; 9:12; 17:20; 5:8; 13:16; 21:24];
n = 3;

rows = reshape(1:size(matrix, 1), n, []).';
res = reshape(matrix(rows, :).', [], n).';
```

The result is:

```
res =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it works. Thank you. I've imported the data w/o the header (cat1, cat2, ...) for now.

Comment: @Sensei Great. Please consider marking this question as accepted by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons.

Comment: Of course. I got a few questions left about the solution provided by Amro. Should I still already accept you answer?

Comment: @Sensei You should accept the answer which has been the most helpful to you, to indicate other users seeking for an answer to a similar question. Take your time :)

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Try the following:

```
%# dataset stored in a cell array
data = {
    'Cat1'   1  2  3  4
    'Cat2'   9 10 11 12
    'Cat3'  17 18 19 20
    'Cat1'   5  6  7  8
    'Cat2'  13 14 15 16
    'Cat3'  21 22 23 24
};

%# get all possible values of first column,
%# and map them to integer indices
[L,~,IDX] = unique(data(:,1));

%# for each possible "category"
groups = cell(max(IDX),1);
for i=1:max(IDX)
    %# get the rows of numeric data matching current category
    M = data(IDX==i, 2:end)';

    %# flatten matrix into a vector and store in cell (row-major order)
    groups{i} = [M{:}];
end
```

Now you can access the i-th "cat" vector as: `groups{i}`

```
>> [cat1,cat2,cat3] = deal(groups{:})
cat1 =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
cat2 =
     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
cat3 =
    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
```

Note that the matching "cat" labels are stored in `L{i}` (the mapping keys)

Comment: Instead of using `data(:,1)` as the first argument to `ismember` I think it would be more general if you use `L{i}` where `L = unique(data(:,1));`. `length(L)` should equal `numel(groups)`

Comment: I am very inexperienced with Matlab (as you have probably guessed correctly), so I don't really understand what your code does. Would you mind explaining it? What I get is you create a cell array called groups with dimesions 3x1. For loop from first element to last element. `numel(groups)` equals 3. But what you do from there, i only can speculate. And also can do a stacked bar plot with this type of data?

Comment: @Sensei `ismember` finds which rows in the original data have the same 'Cat' string, then they are extracted into a new cell-array `M`, concatenated together and stored in the appropriate cell in `groups`.

Comment: @Amro While you're at it, you should consider applying 'unique' on the 'Cat' strings instead of preallocating `groups` with a predetermined size. However, the title of the question says "every n-th" row, I think using the 'Cat' strings is an overkill.

Comment: Thanks everybody for contributing. I'll stick with Eitan T's answer. I think the values are easier to reference this way. I couldn't extract only a single value from an array saved into a another cell array.

Comment: @Sensei Yes, you can. For instance, extract the third value from the first row with `groups{1}{3}`.

Comment: @Sensei and the others: thanks, I implemented your suggestions. I added more comments at each step.

Comment: This is exactly why the stack community is one of the BEST ever. Have a great day y'all!!! ;-D