# Matching rows in CSV data sets

Tags: matlab, loops, csv, cell, import-from-csv

In MATLAB, I really need someones expertise. I have a csv file like the following (extra spaces is just to make it readable):

```
State,   Damage,    Blizzards,
Texas,   2,         2,
Alabama, 1,         0,
Alabama, 0,         1,
Texas,   5,         3,
Montana, 0,         8,
Arizona, 0,         0,
Arizona, 0,         1,
Texas,   8,         5,
```

I have applied textread and strcmpi. Here is the goal: I need to develop a loop that gets each individual state with the associated data with the state and plot it on one plot, and repeats for each state until finish. So for loop one: Alabama has two data sets, so I need this extracted and plotted. Loop two: Texas has 3 data sets so I need this extracted and plotted. And the process repeats until all the states have been applied.

Here is the code:

```
filename = 'datacollect.csv'
[State,Damage,Blizzards] = ...
textread(filename,'%s %d... %d','delimiter',',','headerlines',1);
index1 = strcmpi(State, 'Texas');
Damage = Damage(index1)
Blizzards = Blizzards(index1)
plot(Damage,Blizzards) %for Texas
```

Trying to make it a loop, automatic, so I don't have to hard code it.

I really need a solution -- even if you are unsure.

Comment: What's the name of the files containing the datasets and where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you gotten as far as reading all the data into a cell matrix?

Comment: Yes.  I have applied textread.  [State,Damage,Blizzards] = textread....etc.  Then I use strcmpi to extract the strings I want.  index1 = strcmpi(Blizzards,'Montana').  I'm trying to not hard code each state but make a loop.

Comment: Post your code. I suggest you use `state= unique(data(:,1))`, then loop through state and use `ismember` to find the rows.

Comment: Actually I think Amro's answer here will solve your problem almost exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437937/concatenate-every-n-th-row/16438792#comment23577949_16438792

Comment: Dan, could you show me how to use ismember to find the rows?  I will post my code in a few minutes.

Comment: @Dan _Almost_ exactly, because after `textread` the data is stored in cell arrays, each containing an array (vector) of the values in the corresponding column.

Comment: Dan, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437937/concatenate-every-n-th-row/16438792#comment23577949_16438792) should definitely point you in the right direction, but here's the full solution spelt out for you, in case you're still having trouble:

```
%// Parse CSV file
[States, Damage, Blizzards] = textread(csvfilename, '%s %d %d', ...
    'delimiter', ',', 'headerlines', 1);

%// Parse data and store in an array of structs
[U, ix, iu] = unique(States);        %// Find unique state names
S = struct('state', U);              %// Create a struct for each state
for k = 1:numel(U)
    idx = (iu == k);                 %// Indices of rows matching current state
    S(k).damage = Damage(idx);       %// Add damage information
    S(k).blizzards = Blizzards(idx); %// Add blizards information
end
```

The resulting `S` is an array of [structs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with the fields `state`, `damage` and `blizzards`.

Now you can loop over this array of structs, accessing fields of the corresponding struct in each iteration. For instance, to access the `damage` values of Alabama (the second struct), you can do `S(2).damage`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  I have been researching many articles on stackoverflow (and I will read the link to increase my understanding)...really I have spent a couple of days on this.  I really appreciate it.